# how to resize picture box and picture in it depend on form's size

Tags: c#

I want make a form whit a picture box and resizing the picture box on resizing the form also resizing the picture in the picture box on resizing the picture box.how do it? sorry for my poor english

Comment: Change the Anchor property in the Properties window, also anchor to the right and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Control control = (Control)sender;


   double percentage = 0.7;    
   int width = control.Size.Width;
   //width = (int)Math.Round(test*perc); imagewidth 70% of form width
   int heigth = control.Size.Width;

   picturebox1.Size = new Size(width,height);  

}
```

Comment: Docking would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Dock** the picture box in the parent form, and change the `SizeMode` property of the **picturebox** to stretch